# Are Hodge numbers topological invariants for manifolds that admit a Kähler structure?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory

I know that all fibers in a analytic fibration (proper, holomorpic) are homeomorphic, and if the fibers are Kählerian manifolds, then they have equal Hodge numbers.

Could it happen however that a manifold admits different Kählerian structures for which the Hodge numbers differ?

Comment: Yes they can be different.  See the accepted answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279837/dolbeault-cohomology-is-invariant-under-homeomorphisms

Comment: Great, thank you very much for the link!

Answer (score 0):

**An Explicit Example.** Let $\displaystyle\Sigma\equiv\mathbb{CP}^2\#8\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$ be the blow-up of complex projective plane $\mathbb{CP}^2$ at $8$ points in general position, this is a *Del Pezzo surface* ([proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107345/blowing-up-general-k-points-on-the-plane) and [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_Pezzo_surface)), so it is an algebraic complex surface; in particular, it is a compact Kähler surface. By theorem 1 in D. Kotschick (1989) - *On manifolds homeomorphic to $\displaystyle\mathbb{CP}^2\#8\overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$*, Invent. Math., 95 **3**, 591–600, $\Sigma$ is homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to the [Barlow surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barlow_surface), which is another compact Kähler surface.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. However, if I'm not mistaken, they both have the same Hodge numbers...

Comment: Yes, it is; but I don't know neither a proof nor a source for a proof.

Comment: They are both rational, so they can only differ in their $h^{1,1}$. Since they are homeomorphic, their Betti numbers $b_i$ are equal, and $b_2 = h^{0,2} + h^{1,1} + h^{2,0}$.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question; I meant: I know the common Hodge diamond of these varieties, but I don't know neither a proof nor a source for a proof.