# Can a complex manifold that is not a Calabi-Yau manifold be homeomorphic to a Calabi-Yau manifold?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds, k3-surfaces

This is a kind of a follow up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2921801/9911), which actually already had an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/279837/9911), in which it is asserted that Hodge numbers in general are *not* topological invariants. Could it be so extreme that a Calabi-Yau $n$-manifold (compact Kähler with $h^{k,0} = 0$ for $0 < k < n$, trivial canonical bundle) is homeomorphic to a non-Calabi-Yau complex manifold?

In other words, could there be a topological manifold that admits one complex structure for which it is Calabi-Yau, and another for which it isn't?

Comment: Among simply connected 4-manifolds, the only Calabi-Yau manifold is the $K3$ surface, so we need to know whether or not it can support complex structures with nonzero $c_1$. Maybe there is a low-tech answer, but in fact a Kahler structure on $K3$ always has $c_1 = 0$ by techniques of Seiberg-Witten theory from the 90s. I would guess there are counterexamples in higher dimensions.

Comment: Note that Hodge numbers $h^{k,0}$ are birational invariant. In particular, the blowup of a CY variety has the same $h^{k,0}$ as the original one. So, I don't think it is a good idea to define the CY property in terms of Hodge numbers.

Comment: @Sasha In fact the condition on the Hodge numbers is equivalent to the holonomy being exactly $SU(n)$ rather than contained in it, but has the advantage that it is defined in purely algebraic terms.

Comment: @Sasha Ah, I meant to add triviality of the canonical bundle but didn't write that. Was that your objection? I'll edit.

Comment: @doetoe That was definitely his objection, as it is crucial. That's what gives the reduction to holonomy inside $SU$ (after applying Calabi's conjecture / Yau's theorem).

Comment: @MikeMiller In light of the reference posted by Armandoj18eos, probably your argument shows that a complex surface *diffeomorphic* to a K3 surface has to be K3 itself, but this does not need to hold for a surface homeomorphic to a K3 surface.

Comment: @doetoe Yes, I know. Sorry for not making the distinction clear. To avoid exotic structures you should phrase this about complex structures on a fixed smooth manifold. It is a little silly to work with different smooth structures, as 'complex structure' only makes sense on a differentiable manifold to begin with.

Comment: @MikeMiller My guess would actually have been that Calabi-Yau-ness was a topological property! Now I am curious if it can be a differential invariant (from your first comment I infer that you expect that it isn't). I'll post this as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is!

There exist the *homotopy type K3-surfaces* which are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic to K3-surfaces.

You can consult D. Huybrechts (2016) *Lectures on K3-surfaces*, Cambridge University Press; chapter 1, remark 3.6.ii.

Comment: Great, thanks! I guess a follow-up question would be if a complex manifold that is not a Calabi-Yau manifold can be *diffeomorphic* to a Calabi-Yau manifold?

Comment: Do you happen to know if the K3 surface it is homeomorphic to is algebraic? I'm wondering if it could be that dimension 2 is somehow exceptional.

Comment: If I'm not wrong: if a $K3$-surface $X$ is homeomorphic to an algebraic one $Y$ then $X$ is algebraic as well. See Barth W., Peters C., Van de Ven A. (1984) _Compact complex surfaces_, Springer-Verlag; Chapter VIII.

Comment: I doubt that can be true, as all K3 surfaces are diffeomorphic (chapter VIII.2)