# Is the Calabi-Yau property of a smooth manifold a differential invariant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds, k3-surfaces

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2923353/9911) I asked if it could happen that two complex manifolds are homeomorphic, and one of them is a Calabi-Yau manifold but the other isn't. [It turns out](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2925134/9911) that there are complex surfaces that are homeomorphic to a K3 surface, but are not K3 surfaces themselves.

On the other hand, in the first comment to that question, Mike Miller asserts that this cannot happen for *diffeomorphic* surfaces.

Is it possible in higher dimensions that a Calabi-Yau manifold (compact Kähler with $h^{k,0} = 0$ for $0 < k < n$, trivial canonical bundle) is diffeomorphic to another complex manifold that is not Calabi-Yau?

Comment: Diffeomorphic simply-connected surfaces, at least. :)

Comment: As an observation, it is an open question whether given any closed almost complex manifold $(M,J)$ of dimension $2n > 4$, you may deform $J$ to $J'$, an almost complex structure coming from a *legitimate* complex structure. So one might want to ask the more basic question,  "can $M$ support $J_1. J_2$ so that $c_1(J_1) = 0 \neq c_1(J_2)$?" My gut feeling is "sure, why not?" without any serious thought behind it.

Comment: @MikeMiller Interesting. My gut feeling unfortunately is almost completely lacking in this, so I'd have to chew on this for a bit. As for your other comment, I thought that all K3 surfaces were simply connected, actually that all were diffeomorpic. Maybe it depends on the exact definition you use.

Comment: 1) When someone says "All K3 surfaces are diffeomorphic", they mean "Any two compact complex surfaces with $c_1(M, J) = 0$ are diffeomorphic." But we have already put the complex structure on and assumed a property about it. Now, it *is* true that any other complex structure on the same underlying smooth manifold is Calabi-Yau, but this is a nontrivial theorem of Seiberg-Witten theory. 2) The second sentence looks like one is asserting this property for all surfaces, not just K3s, so I was being careful.

Comment: An example of a four-manifold supporting $J_1$ and $J_2$ with $c_1(J_1) = 0$, $c_1(J_2) \neq 0$ is provided by any parallelizable $M^4$ with a non-torsion class $\alpha \in H^2(M; Z)$ whose square is 0. (By Wu’s criterion there are then J’s with $c_1 = 0$ and $c_1 = 2\alpha$.) An example of such a manifold is the torus, or more generally any nilmanifold. In dimension 6, from the answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63439/how-can-we-detect-the-existence-of-almost-complex-structures we can conclude that the six-torus admits such J’s as well.