# What does it mean for a (non-smooth) homeomorphism between oriented smooth manifolds to be orientation preserving?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, orientation

The definitions I know of orientability of manifolds are in terms of tangent spaces. However, for example in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/290877/9911) there is mention of orientation preserving homeomophisms (between orientable complex manifolds).

My first thought would be something like instead of considering a basis of tangent vectors (or their determinant), to integrate these to consider a set of short curves emanating from a point on the manifold (e.g. by mapping curves in a coordinate chart), and considering the ordering of their image under the homeomorphism. It is not clear to me that this would work however, since a curve through a point could get folded in such a way that one end of it would give you one ordering, but the other a different one, or so it seems. Probably there could be other kinds of pathological behaviour as well.

In any case my questions are

1. How can we define if a homeomorphism between oriented smooth manifolds is orientation-preserving?
2. More generally, can we speak of orientability of topological manifolds without relying on any differentiable structure? Or even for more general topological spaces?

Thanks!

Comment: For 1. I think we can make a smooth function arbitrarily close to a given continuous function.. For 2. I doubt we can define orientability in those generalities..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orientation can be defined on manifolds using singular homology theory.
The easiest case is where $M$ is a compact $n$-manifold. Then $H_n(M;\Bbb Z)$
is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ when $M$ is orientable, and is zero when $M$
is non-orientable. An orientation of $M$ is a choice of a generator
of $H_n(M;\Bbb Z)$. A homeomorphism $f:M\to M'$ is orientation-preserving
if $f^*$ maps your favoured generator of $H_n(M;\Bbb Z)$
to your favoured generator of $H_n(M';\Bbb Z)$.

More generally one can use local homology groups; these are relative
homology groups $H_n(M,M-\{x\};\Bbb Z)$ where $x\in M$. These determine
whether or not a map between manifolds is orientation-preserving at a given
point.

For details, see texts in algebraic topology, for instance Hatcher's.

Comment: Indeed $H_n(M,M-\{x\};\Bbb Z)\cong \mathbb Z$ and there are two possible isomorphisms to $\mathbb Z$. The choice of such an isomorphism is the same as an orientation at the point $x$. If one can make this choice consistently, the manifold is orientable.

Answer (score 1):

Lord Shark the Unknown has completely answered the question, but let me draw your attention to the concept of a "microbundle" introduced by Milnor. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microbundle and

Switzer, Robert M. Algebraic topology - homotopy and homology. Springer, 2017.

As you certainly know, an orientation of a smooth manifold can be defined as an orientation of its tangent bundle. Topological manifolds $M$ do not have a tangent bundle, but you can consider the triple $E = (M,\Delta,p)$, where $\Delta : M \to M \times M$ is the diagonal map and $p : M \times M \to M$ is the projection onto the first coordinate. Around $\Delta(M)$ the space $ M \times M$ looks like a vector bundle. In fact, let $p \in M$ and $U$ be an open neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $U \times U$ is an open neighborhood of $\Delta(p)$ which is homeomorphic to $U \times \mathbb{R}^n$, and the restriction of $p$ to $U \times U$ corresponds to the projection  $U \times \mathbb{R}^n \to U$. This means that $(M,\Delta,p)$ is a *microbundle*.

Orientations of microbundles can be defined homologically. See again Lord Shark the Unknown's answer. Intuitively, each microbundle with fiber $\mathbb{R}^n$ admits a sphere bundle with fiber $S^{n-1}$ around the zero section of the base space. An orientation of such a sphere bundle is a "compatible family" of orientations of the fibers $S_p \approx S^{n-1}$, and this is given by a family of generators of $H_{n-1}(S_p)$. For a topological manifold you easily see that $H_{n-1}(S_p) \approx H_n(M,M \setminus p)$.

Comment: I had never heard of this, thanks!