# Hodge decomposition and homotopy equivalence

Tags: differential-topology, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory, de-rham-cohomology

For any compact Kahler manifold $X$, we have a decomposition
$$H^n(X,\mathbb{C})\cong \bigoplus_{i+j=n}H^{i,j}(X).$$
The cohomology of spaces is a homotopy invariant. Then it seems natural to ask if the decomposition of cohomology is also a homotopy invariant. That is to say, if we denote by $X,Y$ two homotopy equivalent compact Kahler manifolds, do we have
$$H^{i,j}(X)\cong H^{i,j}(Y)?$$
The reason I have hope that this might be true is that any homotopy between smooth manifolds can in fact be assumed to be smooth.

Comment: Nope, it's not even diffeomorphism invariant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279837/dolbeault-cohomology-is-invariant-under-homeomorphisms