# Sum of Dolbeault cohomology and homotopy invariance

Tags: differential-topology, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory, de-rham-cohomology

If $X$ is a compact Kahler manifold, then the Hodge decomposition is
$$H^n(X,\mathbb{C})=\bigoplus_{i+j=n} H^{i,j}(X).$$
Then the left hand side is homotopy invariant and therefore, so is therefore so is the right. However, as for instance was mentined in these two questions [Hodge decomposition and homotopy equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782595/hodge-decomposition-and-homotopy-equivalence) [Dolbeault Cohomology is invariant under homeomorphisms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279837/dolbeault-cohomology-is-invariant-under-homeomorphisms), the individual
$$H^{i,j}(X)$$
are not homotopy invariant, in fact not even diffeomorphism invariant.

Is there a proof that $\bigoplus_{i+j=n} H^{i,j}(X)$ is homotopy invariant without using the Hodge theorem, i.e. the isomorphism to singular cohomology?